# Angular 8 - How to authorize permissions instead of roles with ngx-permissions?

Tags: angular, typescript, acl, angular8

I'm using ngx-permissions (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) in a project so that I can manage users permissions on my application.

As far as I can see, we can authorize roles in html part but not permissions...

Here's what we want:

Html:

```
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['voirResources']">1232465</div>
```

Typescript:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const roleMetier: Role = new Role();
    roleMetier.nom = 'ADMIN';
    roleMetier.permissions = ['voirHighlightCard', 'voirResources', 'voirTout', 'voirNextSteps'];
    this.rolesService.addRole(roleMetier.nom, roleMetier.permissions);

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(['ADMIN']);
  }
```

As you could see, I set my role Admin with some permissions.
After that, I load admin permissions for my current users.

In Html code, I add *ngxPermissions="['voirResources']" so that only users with permission "voirResources" can see the div content.

Here's the code on stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poc-ngx-permissions

My questions are:

- can we do it with ngx-permissions?
- if we can't do it with ngx-permissions, do you know another npm packages that I can use? I don't want to develop another ACL package if there's something cool to use ^^

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: It seems your confusion is common and therefore this question also exists as a [Github issue](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/issues/80#issue-357128161).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `this.permissionsService.addPermission(['seeContent']);` or via `loadPermission`

So modification to your stackblitz:

```
ngOnInit() {
// this.chargerPermissionsUtilisateur();

this.chargerRoleUtilisateur();
console.log(this.rolesService.getRoles());
}

chargerRoleUtilisateur() {
    const roleMetier: Role = new Role();
    roleMetier.nom = 'ADMIN';
    roleMetier.permissions = ['seeContent'];

    this.permissionsService.addPermission(['seeContent']);

    this.rolesService.addRole(roleMetier.nom, roleMetier.permissions);
}
```

Alternatively you can just change your `chargerPermissionsUtilisateur()` method to:

```
this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(['seeContent']);
```

and change the order of your `ngOnInit`

```
this.chargerPermissionsUtilisateur();
this.chargerRoleUtilisateur();
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poc-ngx-permissions-qxi4mz

Comment: Ok, thanks penleychan, I thought `this.rolesService.addRole(roleMetier.nom, roleMetier.permissions);` do it ...

Answer (score 4):

With version 8.1.1 its possible to do it in one line

```
 this.rolesService.addRoleWithPermissions('ADMIN', ['seeContent']);
```